# c# code to set cursor position in outlook word editor

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working with a outlook add-in for HTML content email in C#, I
need to set the caret position inside a div to allow user to type when clicking new mail.

Is there any option using
GetInspector.WordEditor to set the cursor position to star typing the email content

Comment: Why did you post this on codegolf as well? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64852/c-code-to-set-cursor-position-in-outlook-word-editor

Comment: i didn't get any support here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - just use:

```
 wordApplication.Selection.Start = 1000

 wordApplication.Selection.End = 1000
```

Where wordApplication is a Word.Application object returned from Word.Document.Application, and Word.Document is returned from Inspector.WordEditor.

Comment: This helped me as well:
https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=1&TID=14006